# Sending duplicate emails on new form submission entry

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following script which sends an email to the appropriate person based on one of the fields in the form submission. It is working appropriately however it is sending multiple emails each time a new entry is submitted and I'm not sure why. Can someone tell me what is wrong in my code to fix this?

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var email1 = "A@A.com";
  var email2 = "B@B.com";
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var message = row[1];       // Second column
    var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
  if (message = "cat") {
    MailApp.sendEmail(email1, subject, message);
  if (message = "dog") {
    MailApp.sendEmail(email2, subject, message);
  }
   }
    }
      }
```

Comment: Use == or === to test for equivalency in your if statements​. As is both items are evaluating to true.

Comment: @ScampMichael tried your suggestion but no luck, it's still sending multiple. It's as if it's not checking only the new row to determine where to send the email but it's checking all rows. I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: How many of email1 and how many of email2?

Comment: As you have written your code will iterate through each row in the data range and send an email accordingly

Comment: You might want to see form submission triggers in the docs to see how you pull the last form data

Comment: @ScampMichael, yes that's the part that is causing the issue. I can't find any docs anywhere for that though. Do you know where?

Comment: I have experienced duplicate emails being sent, If edit permissions are given to another account.  The only thing that you can do is remove all editors if that is the case.  Does the Form have multiple editors?

Comment: @SandyGood, no I am the only person with access to edit the form.

Comment: In that case, I think the problem is what @ScampMichael pointed out.  I'd change those lines.

Comment: @SandyGood which lines? I'm newer to this so I'm having difficulty. Can you provide some more details about what I should change?

Comment: See new answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure a form submission ends up on the last row and iterating through the rows is unnecessary. This assumes you have not adulterated your form submission sheet with array formulas and such.

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  var data = dataRange.getValues()[0];

  var email1 = "A@A.com";
  var email2 = "B@B.com";

  var emailAddress = data[0];  // First column
  var message = data[1];       // Second column
  var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";

  if (message == "cat") {
    MailApp.sendEmail(email1, subject, message);
    };
  if (message == "dog") {
    MailApp.sendEmail(email2, subject, message);
    };
   }
```

The last portion could probably be improved with Sandy's suggestion or a switch>case

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! It works now! I truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

These lines:

```
if (message = "cat") {
  MailApp.sendEmail(email1, subject, message);
if (message = "dog") {
  MailApp.sendEmail(email2, subject, message);
}
```

Should be:

```
var email;//Create a new variable

if (message == "cat") {
  email = email1;
} else if (message == "dog") {
  email = email2;
}

MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @sandygood I was able to get this to work now thanks to your assistance!